# VLC player mutes when seeking

Tags: sound, vlc

In my **Ubuntu 14.10**, I have **VLC 2.2.0** installed. I encounter this annoying problem that VLC mutes when I seek forward or backward through a video. I have to do few seeks backward and forward again to get the sound back. This happens almost all the time when I seek using keyboard or mouse. Is this a bug of VLC? or is this something else that I can fix?

Thank you.

Comment: See if this works: _Tools > Preferences > Audio_, set _Output module_ to **ALSA audio output**, then set _Device_ to **PulseAudio Sound Server**.

Comment: In my case, output module was set to **Automatic**. I changed it to **PulseAudio** and then to **ALSA**, but no luck.

Comment: When you changed output module to ALSA, did you set _Device_ to "PulseAudio Sound Server"? (Notice that the _Device_ option is hidden and it's shown when you select ALSA for _Output module_.)

Comment: Yes. But problem is still there.

Comment: I confirm this problem on 14.04 and VLC 2.2.1. Happens with mp4 and avi. Maybe other formats too, haven't tried. Stereoclammarks's answer helped, I switched to ALSA output.

Comment: Xubuntu 15.04 with VLC 2.2.0 same problem. A temporary fix is to disable/enable the audio track by going to Audio -> Audio Track -> Disable and then Audio -> Audio Track -> Track 1 (English)

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows with version 3.0.16, I reinstalled it to 3.0.17.4. It works now! Maybe I messed with settings or something, it doesn't matter, reinstall can help ;). Also: `Help -> Check for Updates` didn't show 3.0.17 was available...

Answer (score 24):

I experienced this on two different distributions. The solution was, as suggested above but found experimentally, to switch to "ALSA audio output" module with "Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)" device. This worked for both. It changes no functionality since ALSA gets routed through Pulse anyway.

Note you may need to restart VLC after switching the output module and device and make sure there's no lingering instance (reboot to guarantee). Otherwise it's easy to think it didn't work.

Comment: Where am I supposed to switch that?

Comment: Works like a charm so far. :) @TomášZato Tools menu -> Preferences -> Audio section -> Output module -> ALSA audio output.

Comment: "Switch to <a> with <b>" doesn't really make sense. :-| Ironically, changing it *from* "Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)" *to* "PulseAudio Sound Server" seems to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it's just that `vlc` needs some more time after the seek operation to resync and play audio / video properly.

This can happen with some poorly encoded video files that might be huge or just have incorrect/obsolete structure.  Try changing the video file and see if you still face the same behavior.

Comment: Yeah as I said this happens almost all the time I play any video and seek.

Comment: this might not have been the OP's problem but it happens all the time.  I have a video file that took around 15 full seconds to start playing audio again after seek.

Comment: OP does specifically say it mutes. Not that there is just no audio.